# Cx_Oracle (Python3.6) SQL query GROUP BY causing ValueError - runs fine in SQL Developer

Tags: python, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

System info:

```
print(cx_Oracle.clientversion())    
(12, 2, 0, 1, 0)
print(cx_Oracle.version) 
6.0b2
print(sys.version)
3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

I have a query I'm running which works correctly in SQL Developer however raises an error when running in python using cx_Oracle. It seems to be somehow related to the GROUP BY clause because the query runs in cx_Oracle when the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` are removed.

SQL COMMAND:

> ```
> SELECT prop_code, forecast, sum(uc_fc) as remaining_fc
> FROM my_table
> WHERE
> prop_code = 'MYPROP'
> AND stay_Date = '01-MAY-17'
> GROUP BY prop_code, forecast;
> ```

RETURNS in SQL Developer:

```
+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
| "PROP_CODE" | "FORECAST" |     "REMAINING_FC"      |
+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
| MYPROP      |         17 | 3858.2210740962656178   |
| MYPROP      |          8 | 4599.4697955023602118   |
| MYPROP      |          4 | 798.79072149551767364   |
| MYPROP      |          7 | 1096.30162478218624302  |
| MYPROP      |         18 | 4016.37933889910515332  |
| MYPROP      |          1 | 4793.6514493804123866   |
| MYPROP      |          2 | 10070.756632866636683   |
| MYPROP      |          3 | 29910.550761344399349   |
| MYPROP      |          5 | 1820.4588262721241473   |
| MYPROP      |          6 | 15406.887917698571224   |
| MYPROP      |         99 | 3846.232477937824844934 |
+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
```

SQL query in python:

```
forecast_query = '''SELECT prop_code, forecast, \
sum(uc_fc) as remaining_fc \
FROM OY_UNC_STYDT_FCST_UPD_ARCH \
WHERE prop_code = 'MYPROP' \
AND stay_Date = '01-MAY-17' \
GROUP BY prop_code, forecast'''
```

And code to run it:

```
start = time.time()
my_dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='myhost', port=1560, sid='mysid')
con = cx_Oracle.Connection(user= 'username', password='pass', dsn = my_dsn)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(forecast_query)
forecast_results = cur.fetchall()
con.close()
```

Returns this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3858.2210740962656178'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems like the issue is as described here: http://www.orafaq.com/aggregator/sources/450 Can you try to use `to_char(sum(uc_fc))`?

Comment: Good find! That's exactly the same issue. The `to_char` does work. Also using `cast` as `float` works but removes some of the precision. I guessing this has to due with the floating point being too many digits for python to handle.

Comment: Glad it helped out! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in the module, which has been fixed. See this issue: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/34.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to run by forcing a `CAST` as `float` argument to column I wanted to sum. I'm not sure why cx_Oracle can't handle the query otherwise. Possibly a bug?

The SQL query that works:

```
forecast_query = '''SELECT prop_code, demand_forecast_segment_id, \
cast(sum(uc_fc) as float) as remaining_fc \
FROM MY_TABLE\
WHERE prop_code = 'MYPROP' \
AND stay_Date = '01-MAY-17' \
GROUP BY prop_code, forecast'''
```